# How can I preserve variables within a session with multiple users using socket.io?

Tags: javascript, express, socket.io

Here is the basic structure of my code.

```
//Route Handler that fires when user 'creates a session'
app.post('/route', async (req, res) => {

    let var1 = [];
    let var2 = [];

    io.on('connection', (socket) => {

        //Use var1 and var2 here

        socket.on('event', () => {
            // Use var1 and var2 here
        });


    });


});
```

My code works while one session has been created and the code is running. Naturally, when a second user access the route, it changes the variables for the ongoing sessions, causing unwanted behavior.

I don't want my variables to be instantiated on each connection, but rather each event known as 'sessionMade', which is why I put the variables outside of the on connection method. If I enclose the variables within a socket method, I'm unable to use them for other socket.on methods.

Is there a way I can enclose all the sockets and global variables within one session? I'd appreciate any help, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using express-session

```
const app = express()
const session = require('express-session');
const options = {
    name: 'foo',
    store: this.store,
    secret: 'bar', 
    saveUninitialized: true, 
    resave: false,
    rolling: true 
};

const middleware = session(options);
app.use(middleware)
```

In routes.js or in any handler file created for specific route:

```
handler(req, res, next) {
     req.session.someField = 'foo';
     req.session.save();
}
```

Check out express-session [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session)

If you want to use external session storage, redis is a good choice.
Check out [this](https://codeforgeek.com/using-redis-to-handle-session-in-node-js) tutorial.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Would redis be used as an alternative to express-session or in conjunction?

Comment: @Raja redis is not an alternative of express-session. It is used for caching data, most precisely caching session. You will still need express-session in your app.

Answer (score 0):

What about making them global ?

```
let var1 = [];
let var2 = [];
//Route Handler that fires when user 'creates a session'
app.post('/route', async (req, res) => {   
    io.on('connection', (socket) => {

        //Use var1 and var2 here

        socket.on('event', () => {
            // Use var1 and var2 here
        });
    });   
});
```

Comment: This can cause lots of bugs with multiple users and it's not secure.